# How To create a Global Component like Toast in React And Refer it in any other component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a App using React. I want to add a toast component globally to the app so that it can be referred by other component for displaying custom messages.

I want to add the toast in the following hierarchy:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <section>
                  <App />
                  <Toast />
            </section>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

And refer the Toast Component inside the App. How can I implement it?

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way in React. I would add Redux into my project so components only communicate with the store. Then their hierarchy doesn't make it arduous  to get the data they need. You could just make a `<MessageDisplay />` component that renders message when they exists in the store. Then you can just dispatch the proper action from any component to trigger messages.

Comment: i didn't think of the problem using store. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: You're welcome. if you need any help along the way I'd be glad to help as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should install package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify
and then add import and add

```
<ToastContainer />
```

in your header or some component like sidebar which is being used at every page.
You can now show toast messages on any page by just

```
toast.error("this is toast error");
```

Comment: doesn't work for me :/ anything I'm missing? like passing a prop?

Comment: I had to `import { toast } from 'react-toastify';` in all the components

Answer (score 7):

First you need to **import** the **ToastContainer** and the **CSS** file :

```
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
```

and then inside the App.js add the **ToastContainer** on top :

```
<React.Fragment>
        <ToastContainer />
        <NavBar ... />
        ....
</React.Fragment>
```

And then you can use the **toast** popups in **any of your components, classes and functions** by importing Toast:

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
```

and then using it with `toast()` or `toast.error()` or `toast.info()` etc methods

```
toast("Wrong email or Password");
...
toast.error("Some kind of Error");
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: This worked great. I didn't have to re create the container on each component

Answer (score 2):

I've tried that approach (including ToastContainer component), but the toast.something didn't fire the event through the Toast component. The solution I've implemented was creating a function that mimics a component behavior, and instead of passing conditionals through props, pass arguments. Here's an example:

```
import React from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const Toast = (message, type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "success":
      return toast.success(
        <div>
          <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
      );
    case "error":
      return toast.error(
        <div>
          <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
      );
    case "warning":
      return toast.warning(
        <div>
          <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
      );
    default:
      return toast.warning(
        <div>
          <p>Toast not defined...</p>
        </div>
      );
  }
};
export default Toast;
```

Somewhere in the component:

```
Toast('Action successfully executed!', 'success');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Toast component to App as a prop.

But this is probably not what you should do. I assume you want the Toast component to be triggered by various things other components can do. You would do this with state. Make Toast a function of state, and let other components modify state. You can do this with plane old setState, or use Redux. Though the author of Redux would tell you to just use setState.

Also because it is React there are already probably 7 libraries for doing this. [This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notify-toast) looks promising.

Comment: but will it be available to all children component in app? or will i need to pass it each time to the children components as well?

Comment: This is not how you want to do it :) If you do it this way you will be passing the element down through props to all kinds of children and it will get very very messy.

Comment: This is definitely not something you would *just setState* for. To have one component control the state it would need to be tied to every other component that might want to *push* a message to... Redux or some other abstraction of state is clearly the way to go.

Comment: I know Redux is the goto answer for everything these days, but passing state around is really clear and it doesn't add a dependency with a ton of boilerplate.

Comment: What do you mean a _ton of boilerplate_? It's 6kb minified... Super small, stable, and predictable. Passing state around is anything but clear. You have to follow the callbacks being passed through many different components. With redux you look at the action dispatched and what the reducer does with it...

Comment: I didn't mean lib size. I mean boilerplate. Writing actions, dispatchers... It's very verbose and not beginner friendly. I am not saying something wild here... Literally the guy who wrote Redux, Dan Abramov, says this same thing every chance he gets. He's a huge proponent of waiting as long as possible to bring in Redux.

Comment: See this article he wrote last year: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367?source=linkShare-67ba9eb453cd-1500956717

Comment: Yes I've read it in the past... Just becaise he wrote an article about why you might not need it, does not mean it is the wrong choice here. No one forces you to use it. It will make what he wants to do easier though and is much more extensible than your suggested solution.

Comment: Fair enough. I just feel like OP is probably just getting started with React and I think there's a benefit to understanding what you are doing before adding indirection.

Comment: Fair enough, I can agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

Install [toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/toastify) package from npm import it to your program and add the following to your program

```
<ToastContainer/>
```

You may also be interested in [react-toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify) so take a look at that.

Comment: Not enough information/details, downvoted.